# extract specific string with PHP

Tags: php, string, extract

Lets say we have these 4 strings:

1. `string1 = "Hello my name is 'George' and im fine";`
2. `string2 = "Hello my name is 'Mary' and im fine";`
3. `string3 = "Hello my name is 'Peter' and im fime";`
4. `string4 = "Hello my name is 'Kate' and im fine";`

How can we extract only the parts of the strings that contains a name in '' ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you should probably use regular expressions:

```
preg_match("/'(.+?)'/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

See more on http://php.net/preg_match and http://lt.php.net/preg_match_all

Comment: I believe you need to escape the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pieces = explode("'", $string);
echo $pieces[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function to split the string into an array based on a delimiter in you particular case, the apostrophe would work to delimit the string so that the following code would yield your answer:

```
$tokens= explode("'", "Hello my name is 'Kate' and im fine");
//The value you require is now found in $tokens[1];
echo $tockens[1];
```

Alternatively you could use the preg_match to store regular expression matches against particular groups in the regular expresion:

```
$pattern = "Hello my name is '(.*)' and im fine";
preg_match ($pattern ,  "Hello my name is 'Kate' and im fine", $matches)
//The value you require is now found in $matches[1];
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: I have this :  $string1 = "My name is 'Kate' and im fine";
 $pattern = "My name is '(.*)' and im fine";
 preg_match($pattern , $string1, $matches);
 //The value you require is now found in $matches[1]; but it returns me this error : Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
 echo $matches[1];

Answer (score 0):

```
$string1 = "Hello my name is 'George' and im fine";
preg_match_all("/\'(.*)\'/",$string1,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $matches[0][1];
```

Above will match the string of any length between the single quotes. If you wish to match a single word with single quotes '\w+' in place of '.*' will also do.